# Passing JSON from Laravel 5.1 Controller to JS (AngularJS) is Broken by Single Quotes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, laravel-5

In our legacy code, data from a Laravel controller is sent to the view for use with Javascript thusly:

```
$scope.users = JSON.parse('{!! $users or "{}" !!}');
```

As you can imagine, since it brings the data in as a big JSON string surrounded by single quotes, if the data has a single quote in it, it breaks.

I'm going to renovate how we do it, but before embarking on such a quest, I wanted to see what methods or best practices to keep in mind, and want to know how other people bring in data from Laravel controllers to Javascript in the view.

I have tried other things like using PHP's addslashes() and htmlentities() but those seem heavy-handed and more steps then it should probably be.  How best to convert or encode this data from Laravel?

Comment: Are you using `$http` to retrieve your user list? If so, it will auto-parse the JSON it receives (assuming you send it with the `application/json` header).

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best idea to insert data straight into a javascript file from your templating language. A better way to load your user data into Angular, and coincidentally better for scalability in general, is to serve it from an API endpoint. You then retrieve the data from the url you assign the view to using Angular's `$http` (or `$resource`) and load it into your controller.

```
angular.module('app').controller(function($http, $scope) {
    $http.get('/api/v1/users/', function(response) {
        $scope.users = response.data;
    })
})
```

However, if you *must*, you can use the `ng-init` directive to insert data to your controller(s):

```
<body ng-controller="exampleCtrl" ng-init="users = {!! $users or "{}" !!}">
    <!--- the rest of your html --->
</body>
```

Comment: Great advice, but as I said in the question, the data is coming from a Laravel controller.  That's where the data is manipulated and prepared for the page, and is passed to the view with: `return View::make('users',get_defined_vars());` So I really need a way to bring data from the Laravel controller to Javascript.

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with Laravel (not even 1%), but I am familiar with template engines in general: inserting data into Javascript using a template is asking for trouble. You would be best served setting up a View that specifically serves the JSON you need.

Comment: The difference is that the Laravel controller has the data I need.  I know I could use a route in Laravel to access the Laravel controller directly with Ajax and get data that way, but that means making a duplicate function in the Laravel controller for giving the data to Ajax since there is already a controller that provides the data when Laravel builds and delivers the page.